# Save customer information at checkout

Tags: 8, forms, commerce

My customers are required to provide an address at checkout (*Shipping information* pane). They can also create an account after checkout is complete (*Guest registration after checkout* pane).

But the *Customer information / Address* form is empty:

[image]

Is this normal behavior? Is it not supposed to pre-fill the form with the shipping info the customer provided during checkout? I couldn't find any option in Commerce settings.

Any idea on how I could make this happen? Do I need to implement it by myself?

- Drupal core: 8.9.3
- Commerce: 8.x-2.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this would be the recommended way but I got it working using `hook_form_alter`. Customers start by filling their shipping address at step 1 (required) and on `complete` step, I grab this shipping address and copy it to the `customer_information` address field on guest registration, so the customers don't need to fill the same address again. In case the customer address would be different, it can be modified at this step.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  // Commerce checkout form
  if ($form_id === 'commerce_checkout_flow_multistep_default') {

    // Multistep "complete" step
    if ($form['#step_id'] === 'complete') {

      // Get shipping address and copy it to customer profile address
      $profiles = $form_state->getFormObject()->getOrder()->collectProfiles();
      $shipping_address = $profiles['shipping']->address->getValue();
      $form['completion_register']['customer_profiles']['widget'][0]['entity']['address']['widget'][0]['address']['#default_value'] = reset($shipping_address);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen this "Customer information" fieldset on the registration form. Is that a custom field you've added to your user accounts by any chance?

Comment: Ahh, you know why ... this field is disabled on the user "Registration" form mode by default. You must have re-enabled it somehow, but I'm not sure you really needed to.

Comment: @RyanSzrama Do you mean in `admin/config/people/accounts/form-display/register`? I can't see that field or I am on the wrong form.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in my local env't; my checkout pane only shows the fields it ought to based on the form mode. I'd ensure you're running the latest version of Drupal Commerce and possibly resave that form to ensure there isn't some mismatch between default settings or something.

Comment: @RyanSzrama That actually helped. I had to edit the *Customer* profile type in `admin/config/people/profile-types/manage/customer` and check *Include in user registration form*, save the form, uncheck, save again, and the form was gone. I can't tell how that setting got messed up though.